# Good, small Haskell compiler for linux?

Tags: linux, compiler-construction, haskell

I have SEVERE space restraints as far as linux goes, since I run linux off a 4GB flash drive. I know GHC is the preferred compiler for Haskell, but the GHC package is 280MB, which is way too big for me. Is there a smaller Haskell compiler for linux that works fine?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haskell_(programming_language)#Implementations

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a stripped down version of GHC. The GHC bare bones is about 5M.